# Plot 2 text lines with 1 call of plt.text

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I add some information in a Python plot (with `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`), using this code:

```
plt.text(0.0, 20000.0, r'$[R^2 = %s]$'% (round(R2,4)), fontsize=16)
plt.text(0.0, 22500.0, r'$[y = %s x]$'% (round(slope[0][0],4)), fontsize=16)
```

The values inserted in the plot, `R2` and `slope[0][0]` have been previously calculated.

This works perfectly fine, but in order to insert the 2 values of `R2` and `slope` at different places, I need 2 calls of `plt.text`.

I wonder whether it would be possible to use just 1 call? I guess I would have to add `\n` somewhere in order to have the 2 texts aligned one below the other, but I don't understand the right syntax to use.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python : Matplotlib annotate line break (with and without latex)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10284847/python-matplotlib-annotate-line-break-with-and-without-latex)

Comment: Yes! Thank you. I thought I could use `plt.text` instead of using `plt.annotate`, but anyway, since it works, it's good.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `plt.text` and use `\n` as you guessed.  Just be careful with the `r` prefix which treats `\n` as a raw `\` and `n`, not a newline escape character.  A workaround is to put the LaTeX and newline in separate strings separated by a space (which Python automatically concatenates):

```py
plt.plot([0,1], [0,1])
plt.text(0.2, 0.6, 'Line 1\nLine 2')
plt.text(0.6, 0.2, r'$L_1$' '\n' '$L_2$')
```

[image]